# How can I record a user's web session simply using the web browser?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

We wish to do this for support purposes, where the user knows that the session is being recorded. The web browser will  not use Flash or Java, just HTML5 and Javascript. In particular it would be good if there was some sort of DOM watcher tool which could send a recording back to a server for playback.

Comment: I assume you are interested in something more than just click events? You'd have to make sure that event handlers don't prevent events from bubbling up but apart from that, it shouldn't be a problem just putting a listener on the `<body>`?

Comment: This is something I've been wondering about occasionally as well. I don't know if there are any existing solutions that could properly record and play back things, especially in apps that use more JavaScript. You would probably need to add a whole bunch of event listeners directly on body for starters.

Comment: Yes I want to capture everything. The best third party solution I have found so far is http://www.inspectlet.com/, so it seems to be not so trivial to implement

Comment: They could record their session with http://www.screencast-o-matic.com/ for example?

Comment: @Zubair were you able to come up with a solution for this?

Comment: There are products that do this, but it was too hard to manage as people would log in for half an hour, so we found out that it was too unmanageable task, . Instead we stand in a room of actual users and see what they do in real life now.... much easier and useful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SO you are wanting a similar thing to tealeaf?
http://www-01.ibm.com/software/info/tealeaf/

what you could do is use javascript (acceptable?) and add a whole load of events for example

```
body.onClick = function (e) {
    // Do something here
}

body.change = function (e) {
    // Do something here
}
```

would highly reccomend the "do something" is trigger your own custom event so as not to confuse the DOM too much and not get in the way of other event handlers

This page may come in useful when building your own: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html

Answer (score 4):

there are a couple of services that provide session recording of web sessions, eg.

- http://www.inspectlet.com/
- https://www.fullstory.com/ (I'm a user and big fan of fullstory)

Session recordings are very accurate, we use it both for UX research and for troubleshooting customer issues.
It's amazing they do that with just DOM-watching and DOM events (even in not very modern browsers), and without big performance or network costs.

It's a shame but there doesn't seem to be any non-SaaS solution to this, I never found any open source libs that can do it (to this date).

UPDATE: adding suggested open source (MIT-licensed) library to do this:

- https://github.com/rrweb-io/rrweb

Comment: https://github.com/shutterstock/lil-brother is an open-source solution that is used by Shutterstock to track user behavior.

Comment: `>I never found any open source libs that can do it (to this date).`
here's an open-source library with 7.6K stars https://github.com/rrweb-io/rrweb

Comment: @Wis nice! added as an UPDATE